# Pjsip on iPhone using 3G incoming call has no audio when in UDP

Tags: iphone, ios, sip, 3g, pjsip

After downloading, compiling, and installing pjsip version 2.0 (from pjsip.org) into my iPhone project, I am having the following issue:

The problem is when I am using UDP, while on 3G.

**While the iPhone device is on 3G - On incoming calls, I cann't hear the other party, however the other party can hear me.**  On outgoing calls on 3G, however, everything works just fine.

While the phone is on Wi-Fi, everything works great, incoming, outgoing, both parties hear fine.

Also, TCP works well for all scenarios, both 3G and Wi-Fi.

Tried implementing the solutions found here: http://trac.pjsip.org/repos/wiki/audio-problem-local-no-audio

But to no avail, been scratching my head for a while on this one ...

Answer (score 0):

This will most likely be a problem to do with setup on either sip endpoint side with the main cause being NAT.

I would suggest that you setup both sip endpoints with [STUN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/STUN), [TURN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Traversal_Using_Relays_around_NAT) and [ICE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interactive_Connectivity_Establishment).  You may be able to get around most NAT problems with STUN and ICE, but without a TURN server you will not be able to get around all network problems.

If both endpoints don't support STUN, TURN and ICE (e.g. a hardware sip device), then you would normally need to setup either a B2BUA (as a media gateway) or use some sort of media gateway that the sip proxy server supports.

As to the reason why your specific setup doesn't work, it would require the pjsip logs to understand what was going on and more information about the network environment for both sip endpoints.

Answer (score 0):

You should try this. Add UDP transport inside startPjsipAndRegisterOnServer method.

```
{
        // Init transport config structure
        pjsua_transport_config cfg;
        pjsua_transport_config_default(&cfg);
        cfg.port = 5080;
        status = pjsua_transport_create(PJSIP_TRANSPORT_UDP, &cfg, NULL);
        if (status != PJ_SUCCESS) error_exit("Error creating transport", status);
    }
```